# iOS Extension lifecycle

Tags: ios, screen-time

Is it mandatory to adopt the `NSExtensionRequestHandling` protocol from the app extension and call the `completeRequest(returningItems: [Any]?)` once we are done with processing?

Note: The extension I am using is `DeviceActivityMonitor`

If it's mandatory and we didn't call `completeRequest`, will there be issues?